# How do you reference a scene property by name?

Tags: python

Hey I have some string variables in a property group:

```
line_1 : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "line_1", default = "1")
line_2 : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "line_2", default = "2")
```

I need to reference them by name for a loop, but it is not callable:

```
for n in range(1, max_number):
    test = bpy.context.scene.test_vars["line_" + str(n)]
```

What am I doing wrong on this line?

```
    test = bpy.context.scene.test_vars["line_" + str(n)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`getattr(obj, prop, default)`**

A custom `bpy.props.prop` property only has an ID property `obj["prop"]` once the value is assigned `obj.prop = value`.  If it hasn't been assigned it returns the default value set when defining the property.

`value = getattr(obj, "prop", None)` is the equivalent of `value = obj.prop` if "prop" is an attribute of `obj`, `None` otherwise.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
for n in range(1, max_number):
    test = getattr(scene.test_vars, "line_%d" % n, None)
```